# ui-router and angular-translate working together

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-translate, angular-seo

I read different SO posts and blog posts about that question but none of them answered my questions.

**Here's what I have:**

Angular-translate is activated to find the preferred language, store it in `localstorage/cookie` and use that to translate the page.

Most people are trying to do this the other way around: someone enters a URL like `domain.com/en/pagename`.
I do not care about the locale in the url (although it can be there, i really don't care).

**Here is what I'm trying to do:**

But an important thing would be to translate the title in there for SEO and user-friendly purposes. Having:

```
domain.com/find-a-car/
domain.com/trouver-une-voiture/
domain.com/ein-auto-finden/
```

or

```
domain.com/en/find-a-car/
domain.com/fr/trouver-une-voiture/
domain.com/de/ein-auto-finden/
```

Any suggestions to achieve that ? Knowing that the page title should be dynamic, coming from the `locale-??.json` files !